# GCC 4.1.1 doesn't compile some code with tr1::unordered_map

Tags: c++, gcc, stl, unordered-map, tr1

I have following code to test one concept from a bigger program, and I try to compile with GCC 4.1.1 on Linux. I cannot use newer version of compiler due to corporate environment restrictions and so I have to make it compiling and working with currently available compiler version.

```
// test.cpp - my tr1::unordered_map usage example
#include <iostream>
#include <tr1/unordered_map>

namespace YY {

class X { public: X(int z_val = 0); private: int z; };
inline X::X(int z_val) : z(z_val) {}

enum XTE { Xt1, Xt2, Xt3 };

}

namespace std { namespace tr1 {

#define _my_tr1_hashtable_define_trivial_hash(T)        \
  template<>                                            \
    struct hash<T>                                      \
    : public std::unary_function<T, std::size_t>        \
    {                                                   \
      std::size_t                                       \
      operator()(T val) const                           \
      { return static_cast<std::size_t>(val); }         \
    }                                                     

_my_tr1_hashtable_define_trivial_hash(YY::XTE);

#undef _my_tr1_hashtable_define_trivial_hash
}}


namespace YY {
typedef std::tr1::unordered_map<long long, X*> TXM;
typedef std::tr1::unordered_map<XTE, TXM> TTXM;
}

int main()
{
    YY::TTXM m;
    std::cout << m.size();
    return 0;
}
```

Then I try to compile this code, gcc gives me following error:

```
$ g++ -c test.cpp
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.1/../../../../include/c++/4.1.1/tr1/hashtable: In instantiation of Б─≤Internal::hash_code_base, Internal::extract1st >, std::equal_to, std::tr1::hash, Internal::mod_range_hashing, Internal::default_ranged_hash, false>Б─≥:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.1/../../../../include/c++/4.1.1/tr1/hashtable:1014:   instantiated from Б─≤std::tr1::hashtable, std::allocator >, Internal::extract1st >, std::equal_to, std::tr1::hash, Internal::mod_range_hashing, Internal::default_ranged_hash, Internal::prime_rehash_policy, false, false, true>Б─≥
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.1/../../../../include/c++/4.1.1/tr1/unordered_map:63:   instantiated from Б─≤std::tr1::unordered_map, std::equal_to, std::allocator >, false>Б─≥
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.1/../../../../include/c++/4.1.1/bits/stl_pair.h:74:   instantiated from Б─≤std::pair, std::equal_to, std::allocator >, false> >Б─≥
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.1/../../../../include/c++/4.1.1/tr1/hashtable:413:   instantiated from Б─≤Internal::extract1st, std::equal_to, std::allocator >, false> > >Б─≥
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.1/../../../../include/c++/4.1.1/tr1/hashtable:861:   instantiated from Б─≤Internal::hash_code_base, std::equal_to, std::allocator >, false> >, Internal::extract1st, std::equal_to, std::allocator >, false> > >, std::equal_to, std::tr1::hash, Internal::mod_range_hashing, Internal::default_ranged_hash, false>Б─≥
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.1/../../../../include/c++/4.1.1/tr1/hashtable:1014:   instantiated from Б─≤std::tr1::hashtable, std::equal_to, std::allocator >, false> >, std::allocator, std::equal_to, std::allocator >, false> > >, Internal::extract1st, std::equal_to, std::allocator >, false> > >, std::equal_to, std::tr1::hash, Internal::mod_range_hashing, Internal::default_ranged_hash, Internal::prime_rehash_policy, false, false, true>Б─≥
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.1/../../../../include/c++/4.1.1/tr1/unordered_map:63:   instantiated from Б─≤std::tr1::unordered_map, std::equal_to, std::allocator >, false>, std::tr1::hash, std::equal_to, std::allocator, std::equal_to, std::allocator >, false> > >, false>Б─≥
test.cpp:42:   instantiated from here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.1/../../../../include/c++/4.1.1/tr1/hashtable:863: error: Б─≤Internal::hash_code_base::m_h1Б─≥ has incomplete type
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.1/../../../../include/c++/4.1.1/tr1/functional:1101: error: declaration of Б─≤struct std::tr1::hashБ─≥
```

test.cpp:42:   instantiated from here
is

```
YY::TTXM m;
```

If I change

```
typedef std::tr1::unordered_map<XTE, TXM> TTXM;
```

into

```
typedef std::tr1::unordered_map<XTE, TXM*> TTXM;
```

it compiles succesfully, but this is not what I want to do.
Any ideas, suggestions, how to make this work?

Comment: *"I cannot use older version of compiler"*? Why don't you use a *newer* version of the compiler?

Comment: GCC 4.1.1 dates back to May 2006. Your "corporate restrictions" are r#$@%^!d

Comment: Sorry for my bad English - I was meaning 'new' actually. I have fixed this in the text of question. So idea is that GCC 4.1.1 *must* be used.

Comment: You have two options: don't use that code, or upgrade to a newer compiler.  If your company won't let you upgrade, you need to tell them you can't do your job because they're forcing you to use buggy, out-of-date software.

Comment: My "corporate restrictions" is not the topic I'm asking your opinion about. If you can't/don't want to help, better don't flood.

Comment: BTW & FYI I know well this version of GCC is a "bit oudated" but this is what I still have to work with, no other possibilities in the nearest time.

Comment: @ipx seriously, compilers like gcc 4.1 or vc++ 2005 are 3 generations behind the state of the art. even the vendors stopped supporting them. this also means few users here have these versions installed to help you

Comment: I understand, but I'm hoping to catch here those ones who probably had such experience with these versions. I'd prefer to migrate to later GCC but it is not so easy because I depend on the other inhouse components. BTW I have backported unordered_map from MSVC2008 to MSVC2005 (which I have also to use), and it compiles similar code just fine, without additional hacks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's complaining that it doesn't have a hash function for `long long`, so just add

```
_my_tr1_hashtable_define_trivial_hash(long long);
```

and you should be good to go.

---

P.S. I think the reason why using TXM* instead of TXM works is because the compiler doesn't have to resolve the TXM type if it's a pointer, so it doesn't go down the path of figuring out that it doesn't have everything it needs to construct that type.. namely a long long hash function. If you were to later try to create an instance of a TXM object, it'd complain at you then with a similar error to what you're seeing now.

Comment: Thank you very much. This has helped.